# Wordpress installation fails on my local Wamp machine with access denied

Tags: php, wordpress, wamp, local

I'm trying to install WordPress Version 4.7 localy using WAMP version 3.0.6, I've created the database and set its credentials when asked to in the installation wizard and it recognised them with no problem.

However, when I click on "install" to start the installation I get this PHP Error I suppose :

> ## Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access
> /website-folder/wp-admin/install.php on this server.
> *Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) PHP/7.0.10 Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80*

As you can see in the error message there is `/website-folder/...` instead of `localhost/website-folder/...` , is this the error or is it something else ?
If so, any suggestions ?
I've tryed to modify the `httpd.vhosts.conf` file by adding `Allow from all` line but it didn't work in both php 5.6 and php 7.

Comment: Which OS are you running the WAMP stack?

Comment: @jmsweb Windows 7

Comment: you have to go in and give world edit privileges to your install file. Usually you can just right click the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

Find out httpd.conf file. It might be in apache/conf folder.
Add following configuration:

```
<Directory "{ABSOLUTE-PATH-TO-YOUR-WP-ROOD-FOLDER}">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```